# Amend Tkinter window according to input from text

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to run function by typing commands (i.e. if I type HOME it runs home function), Basically i am doing this by speech and i have done all that, I have made this code easier for you to understand. Could you help me where to put "**if cond**" to make that happen? if I put that before **window.mainloop()** it will say window not found; and if i put that after,it will not go to next line after executing mainloop command.
In this case i am giving input from shell(it is dummy code and my main code is of voice recognition that is working fine and giving output as string)
So conclusion is that I want to ask **Where to put if condition so I will be able to perform my required task**

```
#*********************************** IMPORTING MODULES*****************
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
#from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
import threading
from time import sleep
from input import*
#model_path = get_model_path()
conn = sqlite3.connect('portal.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#*************** TKINTER GUI CODE******************
def gui():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Smart Notice Board")


    #********************** FRAMES OF MAIN WINDOW(HOME)******************

    top = Canvas(window,width=1024,height=184)
    top.pack(fill=X)

    middle = Canvas(window, width=1024, height=450, bg='steelblue')
    middle.pack(fill=X)

    main_left = Canvas(middle, width=275, height=450, bg='lightgreen')
    main_left.pack(side=LEFT)

    main_right = Canvas(middle, width=800, height=450, bg='steelblue')
    main_right.pack(side=RIGHT)

    bottom = Canvas(window, width=1024, height=70, bg='black')
    bottom.pack(fill=X)
    #************************** IMAGES********************

    i_top = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\BG.png')
    top.create_image(0,10, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_top)
    i_right = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\aus1.png')
    main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_right)
    #i_left = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\widget1.png')
    #main_left.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_left)


    t1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\first.png')
    t2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\BG.png')


    #***************** TIMETABLE IMAGE VIEWING FN***********************

    def home():

        main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = t2)

    #*********************** TIMETABLE BUTTON PRESS FN*************************
    def timetable():

        main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = t1)


    #******************************* PORTAL SYSTEM**********************

    #*********************** MAIN MENU BUTTONS****************

    button_1 = Button(text = '  HOME', anchor = 'w', height = 2, width = 8,activebackground = '#33B5e5',bg = 'brown',fg = 'white',command = home)
    top.create_window(2,150,anchor = 'nw', window = button_1)


    button_2 = Button(text='TIMETABLE', height = 2, width=12, activebackground = '#33B5e5', bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',command = timetable)
    top.create_window(75,150, anchor='nw', window = button_2)
    window.mainloop()


#************************** MAIN LOOP************************

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
    #print(valuea())
```

[image]

Comment: again  the same question and the same image ;)

Comment: first you need `Entry()` or `Text()` to write command. Next you can use `Button(..., command=function_name)` to run function which will get text from entry and check  `"if cond"`. Or you can bind this function to `Entry` - `entry.bind("<Return>", function_name)` and it will run this function when you press `ENTER (RETURN)` in Entry.

Comment: if you want use text from `input()` then you can use `root.after(100, function_name)` before `mainloop()` to run function 100ms after starting mainloop, when window should already exists. And then you can use text from any variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `root.after(100, function_name)` before `mainloop()` to run function 100ms after starting mainloop and then window should already exists. In this function you can get text from variable which has text from `input()`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_start(event=None):

    label['text'] = 'cmd: ' + cmd

# --- main ---

cmd = input('cmd: ')

# ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='cmd: ???')
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

# ---

root.after(100, on_start)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `after(100,...)` is a quick and dirty fix. However, binding to the `<Map>` event for the window *ensures* that the window has been created. In the event handler you can then remove the binding to only catch the window creation event and not every Map event that follows.

Comment: @patthoyts good idea, you could create answer with example code.